# How to do it in Bicep: Create a Resource if another exists

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I wrote a bicep template to create an Event Grid subscription for an Azure function.  Here is my attempt so far.

I want to put a condition to only create this subscription if a specific azure function exist.

```
  resource azureFunctionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' existing = 
  {
     name: funcationAppName
  }


  resource azureFunction1 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions@2022-03-01' existing = {
    parent: azureFunctionApp
    name: azureFunction1Name
  }

  var functionExist = contains(azureFunction1 .name, azureFunction1Name) == 'true'

  resource AzureFunctionEventGridSubscription 'Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions@2022-06-15' = if(functionExist)  {
   //do a bunch of stuff
  }
```

However, when I deploy this bicep on Azure, I am still getting error saying resource 'azureFunction1Name' does not exist.  How can I skipped creating this AzureFunctionEventGridSubscription and have this skipped and execute without errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not work in Bicep. The `existing` keyword can only refer to, well, **existing** resources.

You will need to build this logic around your Bicep deployment and only trigger the deployment if you actually want something to be deployed.